# Access Mysql * connection variable from different c++ class

Tags: c++, mysql, class, connection, friend-class

I wrote c++ class to connect to mysql database:

**hpp file**

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include "mysql/mysql.h"

#ifndef _DATA
#define _DATA

class Database {

public:
    string host; 
    string user; 
    string pwd; 
    string db; 
    MYSQL * connection;
    MYSQL_RES *result;
    MYSQL_ROW row;

Database(const string & host,
         const string & user,
     const string & pwd,
     const string & db);

    int createMysqlConnection();
};
#endif
```

**cpp file**

```
#include "Database.hpp"

Database::Database(const string & host,
           const string & user,
           const string & pwd,
           const string & db) :
    mysqlHost(host),
    mysqlUser(user),
    mysqlPassword(pwd),
    mysqlDBName(db)
{}
int Database::createMysqlConnection(){
    MYSQL * connection;
    connection = mysql_init(NULL);
               if(!mysql_real_connect(connection, mysqlHost.c_str(), mysqlUser.c_str(),
               mysqlPassword.c_str(), mysqlDBName.c_str(),
               0, NULL, 0)){
    fprintf(stderr, "Connection to database failed: %s\n",
        mysql_error(connection));
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    cout << "connected to mysql" << endl;
    };
```

When I'm trying to access connection variable from the main function or from a different class I always get an error like *variable 'connection is not declared in this scope*. I tried to use friend classes or inheritance to point to connection variable but it didn't work. I think I'm doing something wrong in my syntax.

Here is an example of how I try to point to this variable from different class:

```
Class risk: public Database {
public:
vector<sting> parameter;
Datasabse.connection;
etc....
}
```

Comment: You should not use, using namespace std in a header file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14575799/using-namespace-std-in-a-header-file

Comment: you don't need the `Database.hpp` header to be included twice up there.

Comment: To mark a question as solved please click the check left to the answer that helped you most. Don't update title of the question, please.

Comment: Write an answer rather than editing it into the question please

Comment: Please don't change your question to `Solved`. Instead please post your solution as an answer, which you can later accept. See this [meta SO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-a-question) for more details

Comment: ok, i'll do it right now, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to solve this problem i had to define MYSQL connection in class constructor. here is a code sample:

class1.hpp

```
***headers***
class Flight { 

public:

Flight(MYSQL * connection);

MYSQL * c;

MYSQL_RES * res;

etc...
```

Class1.cpp

```
***headers***

Flight::Flight (MYSQL* connection)

{

c = connection;

};
```

etc...

main.cpp

```
***headers***

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

Database db(localhost, user, etc..);

db.createMysqlConnection;

Flight fl(db.connection);

fl.GetIDs();

etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
MYSQL * connection;
```

declares the connection variable as local to the constructor only. You must move it to the class definition in order to make it available somehow. Alternatively, make a `connect` method in your Database object to explicitely create a new connection adlib. You will have to mirror it with a close method.

Yet another option is to create a dedicated class `Connection` for connections, which would:

- be constructed with a `MYSQL *`,
- be created by the `connect` method of `Database` as suggested above; the `Database` class would act as a `Connection` factory,
- sports all the necessary methods to handle it,
- and would call `mysql_close` in its destructor, to ensure proper termination of the underlying connection.

For instance:

```
class Connection {
     protected:
          MYSQL *connection;
    public:
        Connection(MYSQL *c): connection(c){}
        virtual ~Connection() { mysql_close(connection); }
        MYSQL_STMT * prepareQuery(const string &query) { 
             return mysql_prepare(connection, query.c_str(), query.length());
        }
        // other methods
};
```

The problem with this approach is that you quickly feel compeled to wrap all the API primitives with classes.