# Template specialization declaration in .cpp and .h files

Tags: c++, templates

I would like define my template specialization in the `.cpp` file  and not in `.h` file. Is there a way I can do this?
I am using the g++ compiler

```
//main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "People.cpp"
using  namespace std;

int main() {
  
  Spunky <int> obj3(1);
  Spunky<char>obj2('y');
  return 0;
}

//People.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "People.h"


using namespace std;

// TEMPLATE SPECIALISATION
template < class T>

Spunky <T>:: Spunky( T x){
  cout << x << " is not a character ! " << endl;

}

template <>
Spunky:: Spunky<char> ( char x ) {

  cout << x << " is indeed a character"<< endl;
}



//People.h

#ifndef PEOPLE_H
#define PEOPLE_H
using namespace std;

// TEMPLATE SPECIALISATIONS
template < class T>
class Spunky{
 public:
  Spunky ( T x) ;
};

template <>
class Spunky <char> {
 public:
  Spunky (char x);
    //  {  cout<< x << "is indeed a character"<<endl; }

};

#endif
```

compiler error is:

`template argument deduction is only available with -stdC==1z or -std=gnu++1z`

How can I go about fixing this?

Comment: Not your question but, if you write your template code in a .cpp file, but then include the .cpp file like a header file, how exactly is that different from doing the normal thing and writing the code in a header file?

Comment: Do you add -stdC==1z or -std=gnu++1z as arguments to your Compiler?

Comment: I think if you use the new C++ modules feature. Otherwise template specialization needs to be visible to same translation unit where it is used so compiler can generate the code. (i.e. you need to #include like comment above says)

Answer (score 1):

```
template <>
Spunky:: Spunky<char> ( char x ) {

  cout << x << " is indeed a character"<< endl;
}
```

Is not the correct syntax for defining the implementation of a member method. `Spunky:: Spunky<char>` is the syntax for defining a method which itself is templated not a templated class, the correct syntax is `Spunky<char>::Spunky`.

You also don't specify `template <>` when defining [template member specialisations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization).

The full definition should therefore be:

```
inline Spunky<char>::Spunky( char x ) {
  cout << x << " is indeed a character"<< endl;
}
```

I recommend you don't include `.cpp` files, if you want to split your template implementation into 2 files then give it a different extension (some use `ipp`).

The normal rules for header files apply to anything you `#include` so `using namespace std` [is a really bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14575799/using-namespace-std-in-a-header-file) many recommend not using `using namespace std` at all.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. The error is:  ```People.o: In function `Spunky<char>::Spunky(char)':
People.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `Spunky<char>::Spunky(char)'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
People.o: In function `Spunky<char>::Spunky(char)':
People.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `Spunky<char>::Spunky(char)'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
./ex: line 4: ./exe: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'exe': No such file or directory```

Comment: If you're still #including your cpp file you need to make the functions `inline`